# How to compile swift library project into .so file?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm new to XCode and Objective C / Swift. I'm trying to make a Swift library project that doesn't depend on cocoa or anything. So it's just Swift files. What type of project should I be creating (I'm assuming there are multiple ways of doing this? How do I need to configure the project so that it builds to a .so file? And finally, how do I build it to a .so file?

I'm using Xcode6-beta.

Comment: I was looking into doing something similar earlier and discovered that without "import Foundation" you can hardly do anything with the language (do have a look at the header!), so I'm not sure how far we can go with the "doesn't depend on Cocoa" bit. Would be interested to hear if people do get further with their attempts though.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Swift library for iOS by creating a new Xcode Project and selecting iOS/OS X -> Framework & Library -> Cocoa Touch Framework and then setting the language to Swift on the next screen.

Once this project has been created you are not required to link against the Cocoa frameworks, and can remove any references to them if needed.

Upon compiling this project Xcode will create a .framework folder in your build directory which contains a dynamic library which you should then be able to link against. Note however that I haven't had any success myself yet at linking directly against this file, even though it appears to be a standard dynamic library.

In terms of using this shared object file on Android I believe you will be out of luck, as the Swift language (much like Objective-C) requires a runtime library which is simply not available on other platforms at this time.

Comment: Valuable information. Thank you. Its possible that swift uses the same runtime as objective C. People have been able to include the objective C runtime for Android: https://www.apportable.com/

I may have asked this question a little too soon. Apple hasn't released a ton of information about it yet, and developers are still experimenting with the language.

Answer (score 0):

... I think you are limiting your train of thought a bit or expecting leaps and bounds to quickly swift is ready to work with objective c and cocoa so you aren't going to be able completely avoid cocoa however you wont have to write any of it the compiler will do that for you. but you will still have to use cocoa frameworks or modules like foundation( contains many specialized objects for program development), UIKit, CoreData however these don't require you to write the cocoa. and if Im not mistaken the .so file is made on compile so you never actually touch that file but rather is supporting files .swift

to do it

if your looking to do everything programmatically or if you want to xib or storyboards just make a new project I prefer an empty project.(set programming language to swift and decide if you want core data or not finish the project wizard thing and bam you have a YourAppDelegate.swift you can make another .swift file or a storyboard and hopefully you know what to do from there. Swift book is available on ibooks for free its nicely written

although it will be quite a while before cocoa and swift are completely separate... if ever

Comment: My goal isn't to use this on a osx or ios app. My goal is to use this to build a shared library / core app that can be shared between iOS and Android (Via the android NDK). There will be no UI component to this library. Language features shouldn't be dependent upon Cocoa. I should be able to compile a shared piece of code that doesn't require cocoa. Maybe I'm misunderstanding cocoa's role? I've read through 1/4 of the iBook on Swift so far. It tells me nothing about compiling. I'm just trying to compile a .so file and see if I can access it via Java's JNI

Comment: oh im sorry then my answer is completely wrong Im not sure how you'd go about that, sounds reasonable if you only want to use the basic swift language however i'm not sure how youd make the .so maybe you can pick apart a .playground file and I'm not sure how java would access the values I'll keep looking around sorry i couldn't any help

Comment: nvm on picking through playground I just tried and it has a .swift file and a timeline file. and I also compiled an app that only contained swift file and plist, during compile it adds a bunch of other files and the swift file is compiled as a .o and is in the normal objects directory